# Get latest related item for each item in QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I have a simple model of an `Observation` made by a `Sensor`:

```
class Observation(models.Model):
    class ObservationType(models.TextChoices):
        PM25 = 'pm25_kal', 'PM2,5'
        PM10 = 'pm10_kal', 'PM10'
        RH = 'rh', _('Relative humidity')
        TEMP = 'temp', _('Temperature')

    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    obs_type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=ObservationType.choices)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3)
```

What I want to do, is get a `list` or `QuerySet` with the latest `Observation` of a certain type that should at least have been created within 24 hours, for each sensor. I solved the problem using a model method for my `Sensor` model and a custom `QuerySet` for my `Observation` model, to filter recent observations.

```
class ObservationQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def recent(self):
        return self.filter(date_time__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1))
```

```
def latest_recent_observation(self, obs_type):
    try:
        return self.observation_set.filter(obs_type=obs_type).recent().latest('date_time')
    except Observation.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

I can loop over all sensors and get the `latest_recent_observation()` for each of them, but for larger datasets it is pretty slow. Is there any way to make this more efficient?

Edit: At this moment I'm using SQLite, but I might switch to MariaDB. Would that make this faster as well?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm using SQLite, but I might switch to MariaDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out myself. I used annotation to get the value of the latest recent observation.

```
latest_observation = Subquery(Observation.objects.filter(sensor_id=OuterRef('id'), obs_type=obs_type)
    .recent()
    .order_by('-date_time')
    .values('value')[:1])
```

With this, I can use `annotate()` on a `Queryset` of my `Sensor` model, which returns a new `Queryset` with the value of the latest `Observation` of that given `Sensor`.

```
sensors = Sensor.objects.all().annotate(latest_observation=latest_observation)
```